# Why does @RequestMapping Spring annotation in controller capture more that I want?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have simple Spring controller with mapping:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
@RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(HttpSession session, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Model Principal principal) {
        ...
        return "home";
    }
}
```

It is natural that it capture `http://localhost:18080/XXX/home`, but why does it capture links like `http://localhost:18080/XXX/home.error` or `http://localhost:18080/XXX/home.qwe123.234` etc. I haven't set mapping for home.error or home.qwe123.234 etc. anywhere. I have mapping only in my controllers.
How to stop controller to matching that?

Answer (score 9):

Because, by default, Spring sets up your MVC environment with a [`PathMatchConfigurer`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/PathMatchConfigurer.html) which has its `useSuffixPatternMatch` set to `true`. From the [javadoc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/PathMatchConfigurer.html#setUseSuffixPatternMatch-java.lang.Boolean-)

> Whether to use suffix pattern match `(".*")` when matching patterns to
>   requests. If enabled a method mapped to `"/users"` also matches to
>   `"/users.*"`.
>
> The default value is `true`.

You can set it to `false` in your MVC configuration by having your `@Configuration` class extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` and overriding

```
@Override
public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
}
```

Comment: This is correct. [Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping-suffix-pattern-match) is the spring documentation describing the problem.